# Electrostatic force vs distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I'm doing a lab for my physics II class in college. We're to watch a video that shows two metal spheres, one sitting on a scale and the other suspended from a string. When the spheres are charged they exert forces on each other. We measure the force on the lower sphere by looking at the scale reading.  As we vary the distance, we record the reading on the scale. I've plotted the distances measured vs the readings on the scale, and fitted an inverse square curve to the graph. The problem is that the curve doesn't quite fit the points. What is going on here? Below is the data for spheres of opposite charge (we don't know the amount of charge):

$$\text{Distance (m), Force (N)}\\
0.01,-0.00847\\
0.02,-0.00500\\
0.03,-0.00363\\
0.04,-0.00262\\
0.05,-0.00193\\
0.07,-0.00136\\
0.09,-0.00093\\
0.15,-0.00048\\
0.22,-0.00023\\
0.30,-0.00009$$

Even while doing the calculations with $\pm .001\text{ m}$ uncertainty, the points aren't within their theoretical value.

[image]

---

Edit: I redid the measurements measuring from center to center.

$$\text{Distance (m), Force (N)}\\
0.04,0.00484\\
0.05,0.00412\\
0.06,0.0036\\
0.07,0.00297\\
0.08,0.00242\\
0.10,0.00183\\
0.12,0.00137\\
0.17,0.0008\\
0.27,0.00048\\
0.36,0.00029$$

[image]

Comment: @OmarNagib Yes, that's why I fitted an inverse square curve to the plot, but the points are not close to what their theoretical values should be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the curve doesn't quite fit the points. What is going on here?

It is impossible to know without being there, but it looks to me like you measured the distance between the surfaces of the spheres instead of between the centers of the spheres. Fitting your data to a model proportional to $(r+d)^{-2}$ instead of $r^{-2}$ gives a good fit to your data for $d= 0.03$

Comment: That's brilliant! I did in fact measured from surface to surface. I've remeasured the distances for spheres with equal charges. Would you mind checking the data out? Would you say it's now a good fit, or is there still a problem?

Comment: @AlexD It is better, still not great but better. However, your changes don't make sense. For the smallest measurement the distance increased from 0.01 to 0.04, an increase of 0.03. The largest measurement increased from 0.30 to 0.36, an increase of 0.06. If the spheres are the same size then the amount of increase should be the same for all measurements. I found that an increase of 0.03 fit the data really well.

Answer (score 0):

Because the spheres are metal, the charges will be able to redistribute under the influence of external fields. As you bring the spheres together, the excess charge on the spheres will not be distributed uniformly so they no longer behave as point charges. This distorts the inverse-square behavior requiring a correction factor which looks like
$$B=1-\frac{a^3}{D^3}, $$ where $a$ is the radius of the spheres and $D$ is the separation of the centers.

Also, [The PASCO Coulomb's Law Apparatus Manual](https://d2n0lz049icia2.cloudfront.net/product_document/Coulombs-Law-Apparatus-Manual-ES-9070.pdf) describes this on page 8.